# PC and phone on the same network can't ping eachother

Tags: networking, router, firewall, ping, wamp

I have a Windows 10 PC and a phone connected to the same router. Neither the PC nor the phone can ping eachother. So it says `Reply from 192.168.1.3: Destination host unreachable.` I have a WAMP HTTP server on the PC and need the phone to reach the server, which is not possible right now.

**What is the problem?** Are there some settings that need to be changed for visibility and reachability?

The PC IP address is `192.168.1.3`:

```
Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::345d:2505:82fa:3cd5%9
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.3
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

And the phone's IP address is `192.168.1.4`.

Comment: maybe the router does not allow communication between wifi connected devices

Comment: What model is the router? Does it perhaps separate ethernet & wifi devices?

Comment: Why is wlan0   inet addr:192.168.137.159  when your main subnet is 192.168.1.x ?

Comment: Edited. Sorry the ipconfig was from my older logs.

Comment: Router model is `Huawei EchoLife HG521`